# Друзья шаблонов классов (ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ)

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте! В ходе разработки шаблона класса столкнулся с ошибкой, которую я не знаю, как устранить. В объявлении шаблона класса объявляю дружественную функцию, у которой возвращаемый тип - это сам класс. Как только использую эту функцию в программе, то программа перестаёт строиться. Примерно вот так:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
private:
   ...//Наши данные
public:
   ...//Наши функции
   friend A f(A a);
};

template <class T>
A<T> f(A<T> a)
{
   ...//Что-то делаем
}
...
int main()
{
   ...
   A<int> a, b;
   b = f(a);
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

И теперь, если я попытаюсь построить программу, то произойдет ошибка.

> Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
> "class A<int> __cdecl f(class A<int>
> &)" (?f@[@YA](/users/3378/yandextnu)?AV?$A@H@@AAV1@[@Z](/users/11139/zelta)) в
> функции _wmain

что-то вроде этого.
Я конечно могу сделать дружественную функцию членом-функцией, и тогда все прекрасно работает, но хотелось бы выяснить, в чем собственно ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

friend не правильно объявлен

http://ideone.com/ohWqhH

```
template <typename T>
class A;

template <class T>
class A
{
   template<typename U> 
   friend A<U> f(A<U> a);
};

template <class T>
A<T> f(A<T> a)
{
    return A<T>();
}

int main()
{

   A<int> a, b;
   b = f(a);

   return 0;
}
```

если хотите углубиться, то вот http://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html

Comment: Да, вы правы, спасибо! И за ссылку спасибо. Теперь все работает как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в компиляции, а в линковке, значит, `friend` и шаблоны отработали нормально.

А вот вы наверное не поместили всю шаблонную функцию в header, в этом скорее всего и проблема.